# Reboot the system into UEFI settings

Tags: boot, uefi

Recently I've bought the ASRock Q1900-ITX motherboard and built a computer around it (it serves as a cross between a NAS and HTPC). I want this system to boot as fast as possible so I choosed to install the system (Arch Linux) in UEFI mode sice it boots a bit faster than the legacy one.

It worked pretty well, but I wanted to go a step further and utilize a feature of this motherboard called "ultra fast boot". In order to enable it I had to accept the warning that I'll be no longer able to enter the UEFI settings by pressing a key during the startup because the boot process will be too quick for that. According to the manual, the only way of getting into the settings sceen is via some special software (provided only for Windows of course).

Soon after turning that feature on (it works really well I must admit) I realized that I forgot to enable Wake on Lan and in order to switch this setting I had to enter into the UEFI control panel. Long story short, I failed and had to do a CMOS reset in order to get there.

I don't want to flip that jumper again though - so, is there some generic way of instructing the system to boot straight into UEFI settings that works under Linux?

I tried using `efibootmgr -n` but unfortunately UEFI interface wasn't listed as an option. I switched it to boot from a nonexistent CD-ROM in order to at least see a UEFI boot medium selection menu (I hoped to see a boot error and an option to enter the settings screen) and that partially worked - the menu was shown, but I couldn't select anything (keyboard wasn't working - that may be a firmware bug).

I know that this setting is hidden in some of the UEFI variables but it's not obvious which one of them holds that setting and what should be put into it. I couldn't find any hints online, so I'm asking here - maybe there is something I missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something similar was asked on Super User. The [accepted answer](//superuser.com/a/1083166/443006) shows:

```bash
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

See also the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--firmware-setup) of this option.

Comment: It's beyond me how couldn't I find this. Thanks a ton!